# Bash for loop executes multiple echo statements "out of order"

Tags: bash, directory, for

I have a bash script:

```
for j in "$(ls -d */)"; do 
    echo "$j"
    echo "$j"
done
```

and this outputs:

```
dir1/
dir2/
dir3/
dir1/
dir2/
dir3/
```

What I want it to output is this:

```
dir1/
dir1/
dir2/
dir2/
dir3/
dir3/
```

How do I get it to output this way?

(This is a toy example, what I *really* want it to do is cd into the directory, do some stuff, and cd back out, which I realize I can probably do the equivalent with some string concatenation but this behavior is so baffling to me and I couldn't find any other questions on it so I thought I would ask.)

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing the output of `ls` as you're doing is not a good way to do this.

But with that said, your problem is the quoting:

```
rm -rf dir?
for j in 1 2 3; do mkdir dir$j; done
for j in $(ls -d */); do 
    echo "$j"
    echo "$j"
done
dir1//
dir1//
dir2//
dir2//
dir3//
dir3//
```

With quotes as your post has, the entire output of `ls` is enclosed in quotes, so therefore it is treated as **one single argument**, causing the `for` loop to iterate only once, with the entire output `ls` as an argument.  Your code dutifully prints the entire output of `ls` twice.

Rather than using `ls`, a better way to construct your example would be:

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec printf '%s\n%s\n' "{}" "{}" \;
```

Comment: removing the quotes from around `$(ls)` helps only as long as no directory name contains whitespace (let alone glob characters). `Holiday 2019/` would show up as two strings, etc.

Comment: @ilkkachu Agreed.  Hence my comment that parsing `ls` is not a good method for this, and my inclusion of a better method which **does** handle whitespace and glob characters.  However, when the OP asks why their output is ordered the way it is, the answer to that question is, because the OP quoted the `ls` output.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop does exactly *one* iteration.  In this iteration, the variable `j` has the value

```
dir1/
dir2/
dir3/
```

and you output it twice.

The variable gets this value since you are iterating over a single string, the output of `ls -d */`.

To loop over the subdirectories, use

```sh
for dirpath in */; do
    printf '%s\n' "$dirpath"
    printf '%s\n' "$dirpath"
done
```

That is, there is no need to use `ls` at all (`ls` is for *visual inspection* only).

To `cd` into a directory in each iteration, do the `cd` in a subshell together with whatever operation you need to do there.  That way you don't have to `cd` back, as the current working directory is local to the subshell:

```sh
for dirpath in */; do
    ( cd -- "$dirpath" && some-command )
done
```

It's only ever necessary to `cd` into the directory if you need to change the current working directory for whatever `some-command` is though. Most things would be able to be done from the original working directory.